# How to add message status on Firebase (iOS App on Swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, chat

On a chat App built on Firebase (App is iOS only) I want to implement statuses for messages but developers keep telling me that Firebase does not allow this, and I do not believe them. Currently I have correctly set one status "SEEN" but I want to set the other statuses as well to keep user informed on the status of their message. There is also status SENT but I am not sure if it means message was sent to server or message was delivered to user's device. Any hint would be greatly appreciated of how these other statuses can be implemented. 
So, I am looking for:
1-Status that message is uploading to server (when slow internet)
2-Status that message has reached server and is ready to deliver to receiver
3-Status has been delivered to user's phone but he has not see the message yet.
4-Message was seen by user. (only this status works at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional fields to your database, for example, "Seen".
[image]

In this way, you can add other necessary information.